# annotation lib which works with private fields?

Tags: android, annotations

My activity snippet:

```
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @BindView(R.id.productTitleTextView)
  TextView productTitleTextView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shopping_details);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        productTitleTextView.setText("Hello");
}
```

OK. It's work fine.

But I think this **violates encapsulation**, because fields are not private.
I do not want anybody to know about inner fileds of Activity.

So the ideal solution should be somehing like this:

```
@BindView(R.id.productTitleTextView)
private TextView productTitleTextView;
```

The question is:

Has Android's annotation lib that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

They can't not be private because otherwise it could not access it. `ButterKnife` generates some code for you that contains all the boilerplate code you are not willing to write for you. What it does, when you write `ButterKnife.bind(this)`, where this in this case is your `Activity`, is trying to access every `ButterKnife` annotated member trough the reference you provided, and do a `findViewById` with the explicit cast. If the member is private it can't be access (basic java).

Comment: Maybe has another annotation lib?

Comment: Most of the libraries with which I worked, so that the fields were public, to have access to them. If you go to hide them for other objects, then I advise you to use findViewById